# Unable to add gradient effect to image in Huawei Quick Appp Image

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, appgallery, appgallery-connect

When I used the HTML attribute background: linear-gradient(angle, color-stop1, color-stop2) to add the gradient effect to an image in huawei quick app, the gradient color does not take effect, but it can apply to the text element for a quick app.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image is opaque. Therefore, even if the gradient background is set, it cannot be seen because it is covered by the image above.

You can set the **stack** element as a parent of the **image** element, set the **div** element to cover the **image** element, and set the gradient background on the **div** element. (You do not need to set the gradient background on the **image** element.)

The code for implementation is as follows:

```
<template>
  <!-- Only one root element is allowed in template. -->
  <div class="container">
     <stack>
       <image src="/Common/img/compress.png" style="width: 100%; height: 300px"></image>
       <div style="width: 100%; height: 300px;background: repeating-linear-gradient( rgba(255, 0, 0, .5),rgba(0, 0, 255, .5));"></div>
     </stack>
 
    <text style="background: repeating-linear-gradient( rgba(255, 0, 0, .5),rgba(0, 0, 255, .5));"> nice scene,  beautiful </text>
  </div>
</template>
```

**Final Effect**

[image]

For more information, please refer to:

[Gradient style of the quick app](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/quickApp-References/quickapp-common-settings#h1-1575449409015?ha_source=hms1)

[Quick app materials](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/quickApp-Guides/quickapp-introduction?ha_source=hms1)